# Preventing headings from breaking on a new line SCSS/CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

Here is my html:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a  href="abc.com">Text 0</a></li>
        <li><a href="aaa.com">Text 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#some-section">Text Heading</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is my CSS:

```
      ul{
        position: relative;
        top: -1.5rem;
        left: -18rem;
        list-style-type: none;
      }

      li{
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 0.5rem;
        margin-left: 0.5rem;

      }

      a{
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Serif;
        color: white;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-decoration-line: none;
      }
```

They are appearing like so:

**Text0 Text1 Text**

**Heading**

I want them to appear like so:
**Text0    Text1   Text Heading**

One solution I did was to do:
**white-space: nowrap;** for li.

But is that best practice ?

**My second question is:**

Is using position in CSS discouraged or no ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox here to get the desired result. It's fine to use `position` in CSS but it's not necessary to use it in this case.

```css
ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li{
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;

}

a{
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration-line: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a  href="abc.com">Text 0</a></li>
        <li><a href="aaa.com">Text 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#some-section">Text Heading</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```